# Plain structure from OneToOne-related models (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Models:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    # More Person fields


class Student(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, primary_key=True)
    year_of_study = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    # More Student fields
```

**Serializers:**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = PersonSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views:**

```
class StudentView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    parser_classes = [JSONParser]

    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

Requesting single Student:

```
{
  "person": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example Name",
    "age": 20
  },
  "year_of_study": 3
}
```

But I need to work with plain structure like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Example Name",
  "age": 20,
  "year_of_study": 3
}
```

1. Where (in serializer or in view or somewhere else) and how should I do it?
2. I only need GET requests (using `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` because of it). But if would also be nice to know how to create/update/delete such structure as well.

Comment: For a start, your structure requires a single Student for each Person but your models allow multiple. You should use OneToOneField instead of ForeignKey.

Comment: Yes, fixed, thx.

Answer (score 2):

you can create serializer like below

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   name = serilizer.CharFiled(source="person.name")
   person_id = serilizer.IntegerFiled(source="person.id") 
   age = serilizer.IntegerFiled(source="person.age")
   class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ('person',)
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Is it possible to include 'all' fields at once?

Comment: You can use the special `__all__` value for `fields` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have `person = PersonSerializer()` which outputs the person's data. Remove this line and it'll display just `person_id`.

Now if you want a combination of GETs returning person data but POSTs using the person_id, you can do the following:

```
person = PersonSerializer(read_only=True)
person_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    queryset=Person.objects.all(),
    source='person',
    write_only=True,
)
```